# Use javascript to click a mat-option on Enter

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

**Situation**

In a `mat-form-field` I have a `mat-select` that when clicked, shows the `mat-options` accordingly with an input to filter at the top of all `mat-options`.

**Desired Outcome**

The user clicks into the `mat-select` and then the mat options appear. The user then starts to type and then sees their desired outcome so they press the down arrow on the keypad and hit ENTER to select the option.

[Image of the current UI with Filter Active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK3sc.png)

**Problem**

Once the user clicks into the `<input>` to start filtering the `mat-options` the "ENTER to select" functionality does not work anymore to select the `mat-options`.

*However*, if the user does not click into the `<input>` to start filtering and just uses the arrow keys to navigate and then press ENTER to select, the `mat-option` will be selected properly.

How can I force the click when the user presses ENTER on the `mat-option` while the `input` filter is active?

**Technologies**

• Angular 7.0.2

• @angular/material ^7.0.2

• bootstrap ^4.1.3

**input-filtered-select.component.ts**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [placeholder]="placeholderMessage | titlecase" ngModel [required]="isRequired" name="filteredSelectControl" [(value)]="selectedValue">
    <mat-option class="filter-input-option">
      <input enterSelect type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type to filter..." [(ngModel)]="filterValue" name="filterValue" (ngModelChange)="filteredData = filterData(filterValue)" (click)="preventClose($event)" />
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option (click)="onSelect()" *ngFor="let data of filteredData" [value]="data">
      {{ data.name }}
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option (click)="onAddNew()" *ngIf="filteredData.length === 0 && showNoOptionAddNew">Add new {{ filterSubject }}</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngIf="filteredData.length === 0 && showNoOptionNoDriver">New driver&apos;s can only be added by an admin</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error>{{ errorMessage }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

**What I'm trying right now**

I'm trying to create a directive called `enterSelect` that finds the `mat-option` with the class `mat-option ng-star-inserted mat-active` and force a click on the `HTMLElement`, however, that is not working at the moment. Here is my code:

**enter-select.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[enterSelect]'
})
export class EnterSelectDirective {

  selectedElement: HTMLElement; 
  targetElement: HTMLElement; 

  constructor() { }

  /**
   * @HostListener to click the POST button if the user
   * presses the ENTER key - Allows for Shift+Enter for
   * new line
   * @param event   keypress
   * @returns       false
   */

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onkeydown(event) {
    let e = <KeyboardEvent> event; 
    if (e.which === 13) {

      this.selectedElement = (<HTMLElement>e.srcElement.closest('div').getElementsByClassName('mat-option ng-star-inserted mat-active')[0]);
      console.log(this.selectedElement.click());
      console.log('Enter clicked!!!');  

      e.preventDefault();   
      return false; 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the solution by completing the following steps:

- Deleted the `EnterSelectDirective` - I ended up not needing this at all
- Removed the `<mat-option>` enclosing the filter `<input>`
- Added the `(click)="preventClose($event)` to the `<input>`
- Comment out the `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` in the `preventClose($event)` function in my Typescript file

In short I removed all code that stopped propagation on a `click()` and removed the `<mat-option>` that made the input an option when it really wasn't an option at all. By not making wrapping it in a `<mat-option>` I didn't need to stop any propagation.

I am now able to engage the `<input>` filter, use the arrow keys to navigate through my options, and then select ENTER to select my option.

**Working Code**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [placeholder]="placeholderMessage | titlecase" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" [required]="isRequired" name="filteredSelectControl">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type to filter..." [(ngModel)]="filterValue" name="filterValue" (ngModelChange)="filteredData = filterData(filterValue)"  (click)="preventClose($event)" />
    <mat-option (click)="onSelect(data)" *ngFor="let data of filteredData" [value]="data">
      {{ data.name }}
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option (click)="onAddNew()" *ngIf="filteredData.length === 0 && showNoOptionAddNew">Add new {{ filterSubject }}</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngIf="filteredData.length === 0 && showNoOptionNoDriver">New driver&apos;s can only be added by an admin</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error>{{ errorMessage }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```